# Creating and using AAR's with databinding

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, aar, android-databinding

Currently I'm creating some android modules that use databinding, the library modules work fine within the project itself (as a project dependency). The problem I'm having is when using those `AAR`'s in another project (as flat file dependencies), it cannot find some symbols (*cannot find symbol variable R.id.some_id* sort of problem)

Here's the `build.gradle` of the library module I'm trying to use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

I then create the `AAR` by executing `gradle clean assembleRelease`, and put it in the libs folder, then I use it like this:

```
//...
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile (name:'librarymodule-release', ext:'aar')
}
```

Am I ommiting something? or is it not possible to use databinding in `AAR`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out, In the layout file I had on the library project was being conflicted by another one with the same name (it was called `activity_main.xml`, and had another `activity_main.xml` in my host project).

Thanks for reading, anyway.